# I want to update the purchases table quantity value from order_item if the order is canceled in php

Tags: php, mysql

Please check the below code and please help me the correct syntax to used.

```
$changeStatusSql = "
UPDATE purchases 
   SET quantity = (select purchases.quantity+order_item.quantity as q 
                         from purchases,order_item  
                         WHERE id IN ( SELECT purchase_id 
                                      FROM order_item 
                                      WHERE order_id = {$orderId}))  
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT purchase_id 
                    FROM order_item 
                    WHERE order_id = {$orderId});";
 
 $connect->query($changeStatusSql);
```

Please find the below table details

```
mysql> select id,quantity from purchases;
+----+----------+
| id | quantity |
+----+----------+
|  1 |       93 |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select order_id,purchase_id,quantity from order_item;
+----------+-------------+----------+
| order_id | purchase_id | quantity |
+----------+-------------+----------+
|        1 |           1 |        2 |
|        2 |           1 |        1 |
|        3 |           1 |        2 |
|        4 |           1 |        2 |
+----------+-------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

expected answer should add the quantities from order_item which match the order_item.purchase_id = purchases.id

Comment: If it was me I'd start over. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks much for edited with proper way. I would like to know the correct syntax of my code logic

Comment: The correct syntax is so wildly different from what you presently have, it would be wiser to start again.

Comment: Yes my syntax is not working. If you understand my logic. Could you please help me to know the correct queries to achive the quantity add back to the purchase table.

Comment: I've suggested a way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly this seems like *redundant* data and therefore not something that should really be stored in the database... I'm not sure what you're using the data for but it seems like you could do something better with `SUM()`? As that appears to be the intended goal anyway?

Anyway answering the question as asked:

**SQL**

```
UPDATE purchases p
JOIN order_item o
    ON p.id = o.purchase_id
        AND o.id = ?
SET p.quantity = p.quantity + o.quantity;
```

Additionally you have a variable in your query which should be substituted for a placeholder in a prepared statement as follows:

**mysqli**

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE purchases p
    JOIN order_item o
        ON p.id = o.purchase_id
            AND o.id = ?
    SET p.quantity = p.quantity + o.quantity;
";

$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("i", $orderId);
$query->execute();
```

**PDO**

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE purchases p
    JOIN order_item o
        ON p.id = o.purchase_id
            AND o.id = ?
    SET p.quantity = p.quantity + o.quantity;
";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$orderId]);
```